how do i make it function using the top buttons instead of the bottom buttons?
enter image description here
#INCLUDE <P16F84A.INC>  

__CONFIG 3FF1H

    BSF STATUS,5
    MOVLW B'0000000'
    MOVWF TRISB
    MOVLW B'11000'
    MOVWF TRISA
    BCF STATUS,5

    MOVLW B'10000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 

SW1
BTFSC PORTA,0
    GOTO SW2
    GOTO TOPLED
TOPLED
    MOVLW B'01111001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    GOTO SW1
SW2
BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO TOPLED1
    GOTO SW3
TOPLED1
    MOVLW B'10000110'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    GOTO SW1

SW3
BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO SW1
    GOTO BOTLED
BOTLED 
    MOVLW B'11110011'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    GOTO SW1
END 

im trying to make it function using the three top buttons instead the ones in the bottom
i wonder what solution i have to do to make it function that way, above is my code for the schematic in the picture
